# Pegar mostrar e alterar Hora / Data

Tags: android, data

Bom dia! Gostaria de pegar a hora do celular jogar na tela para o usuário poder alterar e salvar a hora que o usuário escolher e a mesma coisa para a data. exemplo fazer parecido com o despertador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com esse codigo!

```
private OnDateSetListener mDataSetListener = new OnDateSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
        int a = year;
        int m = monthOfYear;
        int d = dayOfMonth;
        if (m >= 1 && m<10){
            mm = "0"+String.valueOf(m);
        }else
            mm = String.valueOf(m);
        if (d>=1 && d<10){
            dd = "0" + String.valueOf(d);
        }else
            dd = String.valueOf(d);

        data = String.valueOf(ano) + "-" +mm+ "-" +dd;
        mostrarData();
    }
};

private void mostrarData(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data Selecionada" + data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}    public void onClickData(View v){
    final DatePickerDialog dialogo = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDataSetListener, ano, mes, dia);
    dialogo.show();
}
```