# Como pegar a data atual no Android?

Tags: java, android, data

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e preciso pegar a data atual somente, usei o `Date data = new Date();` só que não funciona. tentei `localdatetime` também mais não foi, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não funciona porquê?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar mostrar e alterar Hora / Data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10919/pegar-mostrar-e-alterar-hora-data)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, importe `SimpleDateFormat`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Cria uma instancia da class, passando o formato da data

```
SimpleDateFormat formataData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Crie uma instancia da classe `Date`

```
Date data = new Date();
```

Formata a data

```
String dataFormatada = formataData.format(data);
```

Saida

```
System.out.println("Data formatada " + dataFormatada );
// Data formatada 21-09-2017
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/umxG60)

Comment: Para obter a data atual e formata-la o `Calendar` não é necessário

Comment: @Isac verdade eu boiei :) Tkx

Comment: java.util.Date dataUtil = new java.util.Date();
    Date dataSql = new java.sql.Date(dataUtil.getTime());

Comment: Consegui dessa forma, pego do tipo util e converte pra sql, no caso eu precisava dela no tipo date mesmo, sem converter

Comment: Você podia definir o formato da data `yyyy-MM-dd` que também irá funcionar.